# reduction from VC to IS

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines, np-complete

$\ L= \{ \langle M \rangle  |  $  the function f that M computes is a polynomial reduction from VC to IS   $\ \} $

Is the above language in RE? in coRE?

Comment: What does VC and IS mean? Are you interested purely in the _function_ that $M$ computes, or also in whether $M$ happens to compute that function in polynomial time?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The Vertex Cover problem and the Independent Set problem.
I am  interested purely in the function that M computes.

Comment: So $\left<M\right>$ is in $L$ if the function that $M$ computes is a reduction that _can_ be computed in polynomial time, even though $M$ itself may take longer than that?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Since VC and IS are both NP-complete problems, you know that at least one polynomially-computable reduction $f$ exists. Now for some machine $T$ consider the two machines

```
M1:
  read X
  simulate T with empty input tape for |X| steps
  if T has halted yet:
      loop forever
  else:
      compute and return f(X)
```

and

```
M2:
  read X
  simulate T with empty input tape until it halts
  compute and return f(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Such an $L$ would neither be RE nor co-RE, because $L$ can many-one compute the $\Pi_2$-complete language
$\mathrm{Tot} = \{M : M\ \mathrm{halts\ on\ every\ possible\ input}\}$.